# "Linker command failed with exit code 1" (Xcode 7, targeting iOS 9)

Tags: ios, linker-errors, ios9, xcode7

When I build my project targeting the simulator, it builds fine. However when I target my device running iOS 9, I receive the following error:

```
Linker command failed with exit code 1
```

Along with a `Directory not found for option` warning.

How can I solve this?

**Edit :** Full Error log

```
Ld /Users/gbs-mac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/xxxxxxx-cbqfydingfpnbjblowdpmbcgwnmp/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/xxxxx\ xxxx.app/xxxxx\ xxxx normal x86_64
cd "/Users/gbs-mac/Desktop/Swapnil/xxxxx xxxxx"
export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=7.0
export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.0.sdk -L/Users/gbs-mac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/xxxxx-cbqfydingfpnbjblowdpmbcgwnmp/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/gbs-mac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/xxxxxx-cbqfydingfpnbjblowdpmbcgwnmp/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/sumitghosh/Documents/facebookSDK -F/Users/gbs-mac/Desktop/Swapnil/xxxxxx\ xxxxx/FacebookSDK -F/Users/gbs-mac/Desktop/Swapnil/xxxxxx\ xxxxx/xxxxxx -xxxxx -F/Users/gbs-mac/Desktop/Swapnil/xxxxxx\ xxxxxx -filelist /Users/gbs-mac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/xxxxxxxx-cbqfydingfpnbjblowdpmbcgwnmp/Build/Intermediates/Celebrity\ Face.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/xxxxxx\ xxxx.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/xxxxx\ xxxxx.LinkFileList -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -mios-simulator-version-min=7.0 -bundle_loader /Users/gbs-mac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/xxxxxxxx-cbqfydingfpnbjblowdpmbcgwnmp/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyExistingApp.app/MyExistingApp -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -ObjC -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -framework StoreKit -framework EventKit -framework EventKitUI -framework CFNetwork -framework CoreTelephony -framework CoreMedia -framework CoreGraphics -framework SystemConfiguration -framework AVFoundation -framework AdSupport -framework AudioToolbox -framework iAd -framework Security -framework AssetsLibrary -framework MobileCoreServices -framework CoreLocation -framework MediaPlayer -framework MessageUI -framework QuartzCore -framework FBSDKShareKit -framework UIKit -framework GoogleMobileAds -framework FBSDKCoreKit -framework FBSDKLoginKit -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/gbs-mac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/xxxxxxxx-cbqfydingfpnbjblowdpmbcgwnmp/Build/Intermediates/xxxxxx\ xxxx.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/xxxxxxx\ xxxx.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/xxxxx\ Face_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/gbs-mac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/xxxxxxxx-cbqfydingfpnbjblowdpmbcgwnmp/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Celebrity\ Face.app/xxxxxx\ xxxxxx

ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Users/sumitghosh/Documents/facebookSDK'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Users/gbs-mac/Desktop/Swapnil/xxxxxxx xxxxxx/xxxxxx'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-FFace'
ld: file not found: /Users/gbs-mac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/xxxxxxx-cbqfydingfpnbjblowdpmbcgwnmp/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MyExistingApp.app/MyExistingApp
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: Please upload your full error at [GitHub Gist](https://gist.github.com) and link it in the question.

Comment: Are you using web services in your project?

Comment: @uma -yes and also FBSDK

Comment: Have you modified info.plist like this   <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
 <dict>
  <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
  <true/>
 </dict>

Comment: Yes but still facing the same problem

Comment: have you deleted previous app in the device.  Check with developer profile is set proper or not.

Answer (score 0):

In your project's build setting remove everything from Framework Search paths and Library Search paths. Clean and build.

Answer (score -2):

In your menu bar, go to **Product** > **Clean** and click it. Then try rebuilding the project.

Comment: @Shameerjan Full Error means?